# Custom 404 error page with header and footer in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using ***Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEA*SE** and ***Thymeleaf 3.0.0.RELEASE***. I want to add a custom 404 page with my common header and footer.

By referring to the documentation I was able to add a custom error page in `src/main/resources/static/error/404.html` and that was rendered correctly.

Since my header and footer fragments are saved in 
`src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/layout/footer.html`

Is there a way that I can place `error.html` page in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views` by changing any configuration?

Comment: Have you tried to create `error/404.html` within the root folder of your templates? I was able to create custom errors' pages without any extra effort. Having default spring boot configuration I've just created templates like `404.html` within `src/main/resources/templates/error` folder.

Comment: Yes, that is working. Basically I want to place the 404.html page in WEB-INF folder location. Need to know whether that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thymeleaf templates for defining Error page template.

Spring Boot includes auto-configuration support for the thymeleaf templating engines, your templates will be picked up automatically from `src/main/resources/templates`.

if you are customize you template location then use below thymeleaf property configuration available in Spring Boot.

- **spring.thymeleaf.check-template=true** # Check that the template exists
  before rendering it.
- **spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true** #    Check that the
  templates location exists.
- **spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true** # Enable MVC Thymeleaf view resolution.
- **spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/** # Prefix that gets
  prepended to view names when building a URL.
- **spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html** # Suffix that gets appended to view
  names when building a URL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
Yes, we are using these configurations. So the template location is set to src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views

But in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DefaultErrorViewResolver seems like location is hardcoded for error pages and we do not have the provision to change the location.

It recommends to put error pages in resource/public/error folder. Is there a way to change this location to src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views (where I have placed my templates)